# mysql problem using php when update table

Tags: php, mysql

This system is based on invitation codes, if u have a code that is present in the database you can submit the input therefore change a value in a row. There are 2 inputs, 1) Invitation Code (key), if exist in the database the user can submit the value 2)Name (user). I done the following code but it doesn't work, any suggestions?

```
<?php
//get value pass from form in login.php
$username = $POST['user'];
$password = $POST['key'];

//connect to the server and select database
mysql_connect("localhost", "...","...");
mysql_select_db("...");

// Query the database for user
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE invitation_keys SET name ='$username' WHERE key = '$password'";)
        or die("Failed to query database".mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if ($row['key'] == $password) {
        echo "Login success!!!".$row['key'];
    } else {
        echo "Failed to login";
    }

?>
```

Comment: `$POST['user'];` sure about that? The post-array is `$_POST`, not `$POST`.

Comment: [**Do not use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). 
See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? 
Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)
 - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) can help you decide which.

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Don't have unencrypted passwords!  Never more "mysql_"!

Answer (score 0):

When you are coding in PHP, `var_dump($var)` is your best friend.

So the first thing to do here, is to print the query.

You will see, that your `$username` and `$password` vars are `NULL`, because you missed the syntax of `$_POST[]`.

After, you can put in `var_dump` what you want, and that's why its interesting, because you will debug faster with this.